# AsyncTask error from getView using a HashMap - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, hashmap, visibility

I have set this up to allow me to change the Visibility of a TextView from on online file which get turned into strings and all of it works fine apart from when I add in the parts of the code that allows me to change Visibility of a TextView. I do not understand why this isn't working. Here is a logcat:

```
07-21 19:00:46.451  21334-21334/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.app.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:68)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2035)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1447)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code of my adapter where the error is coming from:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date1); // Release Date 1 (Usually US)
    TextView date2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date2); // Release Date 2 (Usually Europe)
    TextView date3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date3); // Release Date 3 (Usually Australia)
    TextView platforms = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.platforms); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    //This allows the Visibility of certain TextViews to be set via a string set by the online XML
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("visible", View.VISIBLE);
    map.put("gone", View.GONE);
    map.put("invisible", View.INVISIBLE);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    date1.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE1));
    date2.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2));
    date3.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE3));
    date2.setVisibility(map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS))); //This sets visibility via the KEY_DATE2VIS String using one of the terms in the Hashmap above
    date3.setVisibility(map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE3VIS)));
    platforms.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PLATFORMS));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
    }
}
```

Line 68 of the LazyAdapter.class is:

```
date2.setVisibility(map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS)));
```

If someone could help me fix my problem I would be very happy. Thanks for reading. If you need any other files don't hesitate to ask.

FIX: I messed up the string names so it was an incredibly stupid error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 68, `map` will not be null, so I think the `song` may be null after you get the from `data` (at index `position`).

Just add some logging code to debug this issue:

```
HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
song = data.get(position);

Log.i("test", "index is: " + position);
Log.i("test", "song: " + song);
```

Then turn to logcat, you may find the problem.

If not, comment here with the output.

**update1**

The map and the song are not null. this value may be null:

```
map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS));
```

**update2**

you can assign a default value if it is null:

```
int visibility = map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS));
if (null == visibility)
    visibility = View.VISIBLE;
```

You can add some logging to find out what the problem is:

```
Log.i("test", "song :" + song);
Log.i("test", song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS));
```

Comment: Your Log.i are both coming up with errors by the way. Cannot resolve method 'i(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, ?, java.lang.String, ?, int)

Comment: Also I believe the "song" can't be null as the entire thing works without the two lines of visibility code. If "song" was null none of the setTexts would work.

Comment: Also, I got no extra information looking at the Logcat now. Just this. 07-21 19:30:05.939  21941-21941/com.example.app W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4e1f8) and then the normal error again.

Comment: The map and the song are not null. this value may be null: `map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS))`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix or how this could be changed to work?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can assign a default value when it is null. But I suggest to add some logging to find out the problem.

Comment: The Log for the Log.i("test", song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS)); is just telling me [ 07-21 19:56:17.119 22469:0x57c5 D/AndroidRuntime ] Which does not help me at all. If I wanted to add your default value code where would I put it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33869/discussion-between-thepolodoc-and-srain)

Comment: I saw the data2/data3 in song info is empty.
`07-21 20:10:22.979 23066-23066/com.example.app I/test: song :{id=1, title=Grand Theft Auto 5, dates2_vis=, thumb_url=launchpadsoftware.webs.com/…, date3=, date2=, platforms=360, PS3, date1=1… 
(see full text)`

Comment: So if there is any other question, check you parse code first.

Comment: Are you sure that that is the line 68? check it in your IDE and put here the line 68.   (assuming you haven't change the code, otherwise re-run and  put here the correct line.)

Comment: data2 and data3 are only temporarily empty so thats why they are. Luis, this was resolved and it was to do with line 68 and it was the correct line although the error came from a different class file.